# What event is Ty Lafitte associating with the FBI's investigation into Sen. Williamson?

Tags: the-circle

In the science fiction movie, *The Circle (2017)*, Ty Lafitte tells Mae that his company True You has been changed into something that he did not intend:

> I'm not proud. This is not what I created. **Do you think Senator
>   Williamson being investigated by the FBI is just a coincidence**? We
>   can't be seen together, and you have to promise me.

What event is Ty Lafitte associating with the FBI's investigation into Sen. Williamson?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## An anti-trust investigation.

Senator Williamson is seen on TV calling for an investigation:

> Today, I call upon the Senate Antitrust Subcommittee to investigate the Circle.
>
> We cannot rely on them to say, "We're not violating antitrust laws."